# react server side rendering babel configuration

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, server-rendering

I'm trying to server render a react app, I configured babel with preset-env in order to allow the use of import statement but it seems to be not working, ,when I launch the server I get this error :`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

package.json :

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "env",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  }, 

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "jest": "^19.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "pm2": "^2.4.6",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.5.0"
```

server.js :

```
app.use("/", (req,res)=>{
  const initialContent = serverRender();
  res.render("index",{initialContent}); 
});
```

serverRender.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from  "react-dom/server";
import App from "./components/app";

const serverRender =()=>{
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App/>);
};

export default serverRender;
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using babel on my server side my package.json has those babel related packages.

```
"scripts": {  
    "babel-node": "babel-node ",     
    "start": "nodemon --exec npm run babel-node -- ./app.js",
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
  }
```

for preset i have created .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["env"],

  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ],   
  ]
 }
```

hope it helps